# DataTables+PHP displaying wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have two tables namely: school_accounts and school_students.

school_accounts has

```
| id(PK) | firstname | lastname | middlename |
```

school_students has

```
| id | account_id(FK) | nickname | remarks | studentno | is_active | guardian_account_id
```

I can display them in DataTable by doing this:

```
"columns": [
   {data: 'id', name: 'school_accounts.id'},
   {data: 'lastname', name: 'school_accounts.lastname'},
   {data: 'username', name: 'school_accounts.username'},
   {data: 'email', name: 'school_accounts.email'},
   {data: 'phone', name: 'school_accounts.phone'},
   {data: 'firstname', name: 'school_accounts.firstname'},
   {data: 'updated_at', name: 'school_accounts.updated_at'},
]
```

Jack Ryan has a daughter named Leslie Anne who is a student.
The problem is that, 
this `{data: 'firstname', name: 'school_accounts.firstname'}`, displayed the name "Jack Ryan" instead of "Leslie Anne".

What I want is to display is the name "Leslie Anne" in Students column.

This is the output:

[image: table output]

I am confused. I will appreciate any help you can extend to me. Thank you very much.

---

```
    $parents = SchoolAccount::withTrashed()
    ->leftJoin('school_students','school_students.account_id','=','school_accounts.id')
    ->select([
        'school_accounts.*',
        'school_students.nickname',
        'school_students.account_id'
        ])
    ->where('school_accounts.school_id',$this->subscription->subscription->id)
    ->groupBy('school_accounts.id');

return Datatables::of($parents)
```

Comment: in which table 'Leslie Anne' stored?

Comment: school_accounts table

Comment: The issue is with your sql query.  Post it

Comment: Posted sql query

Comment: `->select(['school_accounts.*','school_students.nickname','school_students.account_id' ])` where is school_students.firstname?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Firstname column only exists in school_accounts table.

Comment: sry .. i don't get the relation about two tables ..which data are saved in school_students  ? student information? so should student 'Leslie Anne' are stored in school_students  ?

Comment: Sorry late reply. Student information are saved in school_students like: studentno, nickname ,guardian_account_id (parent account id), level_id, section_id. Then, in school_accounts, this is where firstname, lastname, middlename are saved. So, Leslie Anne should be stored in school_accounts. Thanks for the response.